# Scala generic type with constraints

Tags: scala, generic-programming

I am tinkling with Scala and would like to produce some generic code. I would like to have two classes, one "outer" class and one "inner" class. The outer class should be generic and accept any kind of inner class which follow a few constraints. Here is the kind of architecture I would want to have, in uncompilable code. `Outer` is a generic type, and `Inner` is an example of type that could be used in `Outer`, among others.

```
class Outer[InType](val in: InType) {
  def update: Outer[InType] = new Outer[InType](in.update)

  def export: String = in.export
}

object Outer {
  def init[InType]: Outer[InType] = new Outer[InType](InType.empty)
}

class Inner(val n: Int) {
  def update: Inner = new Inner(n + 1)

  def export: String = n.toString
}

object Inner {
  def empty: Inner = new Inner(0)
}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val outerIn: Outer[Inner] = Outer.empty[Inner]
    println(outerIn.update.export) // expected to print 1
  }
}
```

The important point is that, whatever `InType` is, `in.update` must return an "updated" `InType` object.  I would also like the companion methods to be callable, like `InType.empty`. This way both `Outer[InType]` and `InType` are immutable types, and methods defined in companion objects are callable.

The previous code does not compile, as it is written like a C++ generic type (my background). What is the simplest way to correct this code according to the constraints I mentionned ? Am I completely wrong and should I use another approach ?

Comment: I don't understand your motivation for using a type parameter. Replacing InType with Inner will just work.

Comment: Actually, I should probably ask, do you have a concrete use that can only be achievable by using type parameters? Otherwise my advice would be don't mix parametric polymorphism with sub-typing: this makes things get hairy really fast, as you can see from the answers below. I don't use C++ templates since +- '98 (omg possibly 20 years!), otherwise I'd try to walk the `C++ templates to parametric polymorphism` path with you.

Comment: I do not know if type parameters are the best solutions. I like to create classes with methods which, instead of modifying an object, return an object of the same type. So here the code is quite simple with update and export, but the real code I am working on performs operations on data during the update call, which might be very diverse, including computation of statistics. A fold uses an Outer class instance as an accumulator, and at the end of the fold I might want the inner class to export some results. I need to be able to use Inner, or another processing, hence the type parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach I could think of would require us to use [F-Bounded Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification) along with [Type Classes](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/06/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-12-type-classes.html).

First, we'd create a trait which requires an `update` method to be available:

```
trait AbstractInner[T <: AbstractInner[T]] {
  def update: T
  def export: String
}
```

Create a concrete implementation for `Inner`:

```
class Inner(val n: Int) extends AbstractInner[Inner] {
  def update: Inner = new Inner(n + 1)
  def export: String = n.toString
}
```

Require that `Outer` only take input types that extend `AbstractInner[InType]`:

```
class Outer[InType <: AbstractInner[InType]](val in: InType) {
  def update: Outer[InType] = new Outer[InType](in.update)
}
```

We got the types working for creating an updated version of `in` and we need somehow to create a new instance with `empty`. The Typeclass Pattern is classic for that. We create a trait which builds an `Inner` type:

```
trait InnerBuilder[T <: AbstractInner[T]] {
  def empty: T
}
```

We require `Outer.empty` to only take types which extend `AbstractInner[InType]` **and** have an implicit `InnerBuilder[InType]` in scope:

```
object Outer {
  def empty[InType <: AbstractInner[InType] : InnerBuilder] = 
    new Outer(implicitly[InnerBuilder[InType]].empty)
}
```

And provide a concrete implementation for `Inner`:

```
object AbstractInnerImplicits {
  implicit def innerBuilder: InnerBuilder[Inner] = new InnerBuilder[Inner] {
    override def empty = new Inner(0)
  }
}
```

Invoking inside main:

```
object Experiment {
  import AbstractInnerImplicits._
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val outerIn: Outer[Inner] = Outer.empty[Inner]
    println(outerIn.update.in.export)
  }
}
```

Yields:

```
1
```

And there we have it. I know this may be a little overwhelming to grasp at first. Feel free to ask more questions as you read this.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 2 ways of doing it without referring to black magic:

1. with trait:

   ```
   trait Updatable[T] { self: T =>    
     def update: T
   }

   class Outer[InType <: Updatable[InType]](val in: InType) {
     def update = new Outer[InType](in.update)
   }

   class Inner(val n: Int) extends Updatable[Inner] {
     def update = new Inner(n + 1)
   }
   ```

   first we use trait, to tell type system that `update` method is available, then we put restrains on the type to make sure that `Updatable` is used correctly (`self: T =>` will make sure it is used as `T extends Updatable[T]` - as F-bounded type), then we also make sure that InType will implement it (`InType <: Updatable[InType]`).
2. with type class:

   ```
   trait Updatable[F] {

     def update(value: F): F
   }

   class Outer[InType](val in: InType)(implicit updatable: Updatable[InType]) {
     def update: Outer[InType] = new Outer[InType](updatable.update(in))
   }

   class Inner(val n: Int) {
     def update: Inner = new Inner(n + 1)
   }

   implicit val updatableInner = new Updatable[Inner] {
     def update(value: Inner): Inner = value.update
   }
   ```

   First we define type class, then we are implicitly requiring its implementation for our type, and finally we are providing and using it. Putting whole theoretical stuff aside, the practical difference is that this interface is that you are not forcing `InType` to extend some `Updatable[InType]`, but instead require presence of some `Updatable[InType]` implementation to be available in your scope - so you can provide the functionality not by modifying `InType`, but by providing some additional class which would fulfill your constrains or `InType`.

As such type classes are much more extensible, you just need to provide implicit for each supported type.

Among other methods available to you are e.g. reflection (however that might kind of break type safety and your abilities to refactor).